# Unexplained error with anova_test from rstatix

Tags: r

I am having trouble running a repeated measures anova with the package rstatix.
I want to run a repeated-measures anova, where patients from two treatment groups have reported an outcome in two different time points.

```
anova_test(data = test1, dv = outcome, wid = id, within = c(group, time))
```

However, I get an error although I have no missing data in the dataset.

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...)
> :    0 (non-NA) cases

I'd greatly appreciate any help! Thanks

Data:

```
structure(list(id = structure(c(112L, 112L, 433L, 433L, 448L, 
448L, 582L, 582L, 439L, 439L, 385L, 385L, 51L, 51L, 489L, 489L, 
160L, 160L, 227L, 227L, 328L, 328L, 346L, 346L, 188L, 188L, 615L, 
615L, 422L, 422L, 484L, 484L, 529L, 529L, 209L, 209L, 159L, 159L, 
453L, 453L, 459L, 459L, 401L, 401L, 158L, 158L, 19L, 19L, 204L, 
204L, 230L, 230L, 323L, 323L, 571L, 571L, 86L, 86L, 82L, 82L, 
499L, 499L, 609L, 609L, 632L, 632L, 345L, 345L, 570L, 570L, 87L, 
87L, 268L, 268L, 221L, 221L, 73L, 73L, 324L, 324L, 130L, 130L, 
546L, 546L, 264L, 264L, 341L, 341L, 25L, 25L, 317L, 317L, 443L, 
443L, 223L, 223L, 623L, 623L, 596L, 596L, 621L, 621L, 271L, 271L, 
115L, 115L, 220L, 220L, 17L, 17L, 504L, 504L, 143L, 143L, 107L, 
107L, 477L, 477L, 640L, 640L, 527L, 527L, 131L, 131L, 157L, 157L, 
9L, 9L, 234L, 234L, 29L, 29L, 332L, 332L, 479L, 479L, 521L, 521L, 
70L, 70L, 64L, 64L, 239L, 239L, 153L, 153L, 572L, 572L, 520L, 
520L, 168L, 168L, 556L, 556L, 61L, 61L, 507L, 507L, 502L, 502L, 
144L, 144L, 559L, 559L, 636L, 636L, 298L, 298L, 471L, 471L, 278L, 
278L, 586L, 586L, 284L, 284L, 18L, 18L, 102L, 102L, 12L, 12L, 
335L, 335L, 215L, 215L, 251L, 251L, 262L, 262L, 614L, 614L, 372L, 
372L, 528L, 528L, 437L, 437L, 365L, 365L, 71L, 71L, 69L, 69L, 
76L, 76L, 476L, 476L, 214L, 214L, 472L, 472L, 110L, 110L, 37L, 
37L, 42L, 42L, 412L, 412L, 379L, 379L, 470L, 470L, 624L, 624L, 
363L, 363L, 246L, 246L, 400L, 400L, 393L, 393L, 296L, 296L, 297L, 
297L, 358L, 358L, 409L, 409L, 222L, 222L, 189L, 189L, 255L, 255L, 
605L, 605L, 353L, 353L, 330L, 330L, 421L, 421L, 273L, 273L, 561L, 
561L, 512L, 512L, 36L, 36L, 137L, 137L, 232L, 232L, 456L, 456L, 
182L, 182L, 150L, 150L, 381L, 381L, 510L, 510L, 98L, 98L, 548L, 
548L, 79L, 79L, 517L, 517L, 178L, 178L, 361L, 361L, 505L, 505L, 
487L, 487L, 461L, 461L, 125L, 125L, 580L, 580L, 41L, 41L, 238L, 
238L, 403L, 403L, 120L, 120L, 294L, 294L, 21L, 21L, 538L, 538L, 
633L, 633L, 555L, 555L, 374L, 374L, 463L, 463L, 638L, 638L, 498L, 
498L, 312L, 312L, 442L, 442L, 224L, 224L, 106L, 106L, 184L, 184L, 
355L, 355L, 473L, 473L, 196L, 196L, 446L, 446L, 56L, 56L, 447L, 
447L, 316L, 316L, 319L, 319L, 445L, 445L, 97L, 97L, 371L, 371L, 
557L, 557L, 105L, 105L, 190L, 190L, 426L, 426L, 360L, 360L, 299L, 
299L, 194L, 194L, 579L, 579L, 526L, 526L, 368L, 368L, 457L, 457L, 
235L, 235L, 315L, 315L, 458L, 458L, 407L, 407L, 333L, 333L, 625L, 
625L, 304L, 304L, 334L, 334L, 347L, 347L, 541L, 541L, 500L, 500L, 
75L, 75L, 212L, 212L, 195L, 195L, 452L, 452L, 282L, 282L, 286L, 
286L, 31L, 31L, 537L, 537L, 240L, 240L, 405L, 405L, 613L, 613L, 
619L, 619L, 34L, 34L, 213L, 213L, 191L, 191L, 33L, 33L, 164L, 
164L, 291L, 291L, 14L, 14L, 642L, 642L, 616L, 616L, 514L, 514L, 
626L, 626L, 7L, 7L, 630L, 630L, 200L, 200L, 92L, 92L, 263L, 263L, 
522L, 522L, 645L, 645L, 126L, 126L, 26L, 26L, 109L, 109L, 146L, 
146L, 250L, 250L, 326L, 326L, 508L, 508L, 444L, 444L, 174L, 174L, 
72L, 72L, 423L, 423L, 208L, 208L, 501L, 501L, 119L, 119L, 193L, 
193L, 170L, 170L, 270L, 270L, 568L, 568L, 229L, 229L, 396L, 396L, 
93L, 93L, 241L, 241L, 322L, 322L, 127L, 127L, 482L, 482L, 6L, 
6L, 35L, 35L, 116L, 116L, 424L, 424L, 356L, 356L, 342L, 342L, 
339L, 339L, 247L, 247L, 5L, 5L, 465L, 465L, 111L, 111L, 258L, 
258L, 22L, 22L, 481L, 481L, 536L, 536L, 281L, 281L, 60L, 60L, 
518L, 518L, 350L, 350L, 259L, 259L, 128L, 128L, 478L, 478L, 574L, 
574L, 20L, 20L, 539L, 539L, 511L, 511L, 550L, 550L, 320L, 320L, 
573L, 573L, 52L, 52L, 435L, 435L, 362L, 362L, 607L, 607L, 377L, 
377L, 198L, 198L, 581L, 581L, 169L, 169L, 165L, 165L, 47L, 47L, 
462L, 462L, 595L, 595L, 226L, 226L, 469L, 469L, 406L, 406L, 354L, 
354L, 225L, 225L, 4L, 4L, 39L, 39L, 492L, 492L, 601L, 601L, 602L, 
602L, 155L, 155L, 293L, 293L, 493L, 493L, 585L, 585L, 124L, 124L, 
48L, 48L, 519L, 519L, 136L, 136L, 451L, 451L, 290L, 290L, 202L, 
202L, 618L, 618L, 287L, 287L, 577L, 577L, 118L, 118L, 57L, 57L, 
67L, 67L, 388L, 388L, 441L, 441L, 261L, 261L, 485L, 485L, 138L, 
138L, 149L, 149L, 553L, 553L, 594L, 594L, 233L, 233L, 464L, 464L, 
515L, 515L, 269L, 269L, 38L, 38L, 187L, 187L, 575L, 575L, 63L, 
63L, 534L, 534L, 180L, 180L, 606L, 606L, 486L, 486L, 90L, 90L, 
129L, 129L, 370L, 370L, 172L, 172L, 639L, 639L, 631L, 631L, 569L, 
569L, 351L, 351L, 321L, 321L, 216L, 216L, 450L, 450L, 375L, 375L, 
337L, 337L, 307L, 307L, 564L, 564L, 78L, 78L, 141L, 141L, 249L, 
249L, 318L, 318L, 552L, 552L, 496L, 496L, 327L, 327L, 306L, 306L, 
348L, 348L, 497L, 497L, 384L, 384L, 266L, 266L, 516L, 516L, 494L, 
494L, 542L, 542L, 597L, 597L, 201L, 201L, 310L, 310L, 277L, 277L, 
114L, 114L, 466L, 466L, 308L, 308L, 253L, 253L, 643L, 643L, 183L, 
183L, 449L, 449L, 440L, 440L, 531L, 531L, 525L, 525L, 490L, 490L, 
96L, 96L, 549L, 549L, 295L, 295L, 612L, 612L, 603L, 603L, 558L, 
558L, 151L, 151L, 267L, 267L, 383L, 383L, 311L, 311L, 415L, 415L, 
142L, 142L, 588L, 588L, 147L, 147L, 364L, 364L, 77L, 77L, 285L, 
285L, 237L, 237L, 313L, 313L, 584L, 584L, 392L, 392L, 101L, 101L, 
95L, 95L, 244L, 244L, 265L, 265L, 283L, 283L, 344L, 344L, 483L, 
483L, 428L, 428L, 15L, 15L, 219L, 219L, 228L, 228L, 16L, 16L, 
13L, 13L, 292L, 292L, 192L, 192L, 413L, 413L, 589L, 589L, 68L, 
68L, 171L, 171L, 378L, 378L, 583L, 583L, 480L, 480L, 397L, 397L, 
610L, 610L, 302L, 302L, 352L, 352L, 380L, 380L, 83L, 83L, 113L, 
113L, 88L, 88L, 411L, 411L, 242L, 242L, 474L, 474L, 175L, 175L, 
91L, 91L, 331L, 331L, 139L, 139L, 46L, 46L, 543L, 543L, 560L, 
560L, 590L, 590L, 123L, 123L, 430L, 430L, 154L, 154L, 32L, 32L, 
635L, 635L, 455L, 455L, 132L, 132L, 395L, 395L, 467L, 467L, 49L, 
49L, 637L, 637L, 530L, 530L, 503L, 503L, 593L, 593L, 532L, 532L, 
133L, 133L, 197L, 197L, 135L, 135L, 343L, 343L, 340L, 340L, 387L, 
387L, 394L, 394L, 399L, 399L, 1L, 1L, 145L, 145L, 301L, 301L, 
89L, 89L, 161L, 161L, 398L, 398L, 59L, 59L, 23L, 23L, 336L, 336L, 
245L, 245L, 3L, 3L, 167L, 167L, 329L, 329L, 85L, 85L, 163L, 163L, 
66L, 66L, 28L, 28L, 300L, 300L, 185L, 185L, 408L, 408L, 53L, 
53L, 103L, 103L, 547L, 547L, 166L, 166L, 275L, 275L, 454L, 454L, 
236L, 236L, 622L, 622L, 276L, 276L, 65L, 65L, 644L, 644L, 11L, 
11L, 468L, 468L, 305L, 305L, 27L, 27L, 152L, 152L, 62L, 62L, 
252L, 252L, 391L, 391L, 357L, 357L, 418L, 418L, 629L, 629L, 108L, 
108L, 117L, 117L, 325L, 325L, 611L, 611L, 30L, 30L, 288L, 288L, 
540L, 540L, 206L, 206L, 627L, 627L, 367L, 367L, 272L, 272L, 410L, 
410L, 576L, 576L, 94L, 94L, 566L, 566L, 207L, 207L, 495L, 495L, 
99L, 99L, 84L, 84L, 218L, 218L, 628L, 628L, 523L, 523L, 591L, 
591L, 420L, 420L, 179L, 179L, 432L, 432L, 260L, 260L, 587L, 587L, 
8L, 8L, 338L, 338L, 390L, 390L, 45L, 45L, 314L, 314L, 513L, 513L, 
199L, 199L, 50L, 50L, 58L, 58L, 376L, 376L, 205L, 205L, 211L, 
211L, 134L, 134L, 535L, 535L, 74L, 74L, 460L, 460L, 438L, 438L, 
604L, 604L, 173L, 173L, 425L, 425L, 203L, 203L, 429L, 429L, 598L, 
598L, 565L, 565L, 55L, 55L, 256L, 256L, 551L, 551L, 533L, 533L, 
309L, 309L, 121L, 121L, 100L, 100L, 634L, 634L, 217L, 217L, 366L, 
366L, 369L, 369L, 608L, 608L, 177L, 177L, 122L, 122L, 562L, 562L, 
417L, 417L, 431L, 431L, 620L, 620L, 279L, 279L, 402L, 402L, 506L, 
506L, 44L, 44L, 416L, 416L, 434L, 434L, 80L, 80L, 274L, 274L, 
81L, 81L, 427L, 427L, 104L, 104L, 210L, 210L, 349L, 349L, 43L, 
43L, 567L, 567L, 389L, 389L, 554L, 554L, 544L, 544L, 617L, 617L, 
545L, 545L, 524L, 524L, 280L, 280L, 181L, 181L, 386L, 386L, 600L, 
600L, 373L, 373L, 243L, 243L, 488L, 488L, 2L, 2L, 491L, 491L, 
24L, 24L, 475L, 475L, 257L, 257L, 40L, 40L, 404L, 404L, 599L, 
599L, 248L, 248L, 359L, 359L, 148L, 148L, 419L, 419L, 140L, 140L, 
176L, 176L, 303L, 303L, 254L, 254L, 578L, 578L, 54L, 54L, 436L, 
436L, 289L, 289L, 186L, 186L, 156L, 156L, 414L, 414L, 563L, 563L, 
592L, 592L, 641L, 641L, 382L, 382L, 509L, 509L, 10L, 10L, 162L, 
162L, 231L, 231L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "5", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
"21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
"32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", 
"43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", 
"54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "62", "63", "64", "65", 
"66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", 
"77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", 
"88", "89", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", 
"100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", 
"109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", 
"118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", 
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", 
"137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", 
"146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", 
"155", "156", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", 
"165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "175", 
"176", "177", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", "185", "186", 
"187", "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", "195", 
"196", "197", "198", "199", "200", "201", "203", "204", "205", 
"206", "207", "208", "209", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", 
"215", "216", "217", "218", "219", "220", "221", "222", "223", 
"224", "226", "227", "228", "229", "230", "231", "232", "234", 
"235", "236", "237", "238", "239", "240", "241", "243", "244", 
"245", "246", "247", "248", "249", "250", "251", "252", "253", 
"254", "255", "256", "257", "258", "259", "260", "261", "262", 
"263", "264", "265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "273", 
"274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", "281", "282", 
"283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", "290", "291", 
"292", "293", "294", "295", "296", "297", "298", "299", "300", 
"301", "302", "304", "305", "306", "307", "308", "309", "311", 
"312", "314", "315", "316", "317", "318", "319", "320", "321", 
"322", "324", "325", "326", "327", "328", "329", "330", "331", 
"332", "333", "334", "335", "336", "337", "338", "339", "340", 
"341", "342", "343", "344", "345", "346", "347", "348", "349", 
"350", "351", "352", "353", "354", "355", "356", "357", "358", 
"359", "360", "361", "362", "363", "364", "365", "366", "367", 
"368", "369", "370", "371", "372", "373", "374", "376", "377", 
"378", "380", "381", "382", "383", "384", "385", "386", "387", 
"388", "389", "390", "391", "392", "393", "394", "395", "396", 
"398", "399", "400", "401", "402", "403", "404", "405", "406", 
"407", "408", "409", "411", "412", "413", "414", "415", "416", 
"417", "418", "419", "420", "421", "422", "423", "424", "425", 
"426", "427", "428", "429", "430", "431", "432", "433", "434", 
"435", "436", "437", "438", "439", "440", "441", "442", "443", 
"444", "446", "447", "448", "449", "450", "452", "453", "454", 
"455", "456", "457", "458", "459", "460", "461", "462", "463", 
"464", "465", "466", "467", "468", "469", "470", "472", "473", 
"475", "476", "477", "478", "479", "480", "481", "483", "484", 
"485", "486", "487", "488", "489", "490", "491", "492", "493", 
"494", "495", "496", "497", "498", "499", "500", "501", "502", 
"503", "504", "505", "506", "507", "508", "509", "510", "511", 
"512", "513", "514", "515", "516", "518", "519", "520", "521", 
"522", "524", "525", "526", "527", "528", "529", "531", "532", 
"534", "535", "536", "537", "538", "539", "540", "541", "542", 
"543", "544", "545", "546", "547", "548", "549", "550", "551", 
"552", "553", "554", "555", "556", "557", "558", "559", "560", 
"561", "562", "563", "564", "565", "566", "567", "568", "569", 
"570", "571", "572", "573", "574", "575", "576", "577", "579", 
"580", "581", "582", "583", "585", "586", "587", "588", "589", 
"590", "591", "592", "593", "594", "595", "596", "597", "598", 
"599", "601", "602", "603", "604", "605", "606", "607", "608", 
"609", "610", "611", "612", "613", "614", "615", "616", "617", 
"618", "619", "620", "621", "622", "623", "624", "625", "626", 
"627", "628", "629", "630", "631", "632", "633", "634", "635", 
"636", "637", "638", "639", "640", "641", "642", "643", "644", 
"645", "646", "647", "648", "650", "651", "652", "653", "654", 
"655", "656", "657", "659", "660", "661", "662", "663", "664", 
"665", "666", "667", "668", "669", "671", "672", "673", "674", 
"675", "676", "677", "678", "679", "680", "681", "682", "683", 
"685"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("-1", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    outcome = c(5, 6, 16, 15, 8, 6, 15, 0, 5, 6, 6, 2, 8, 9, 
    11, 4, 13, 11, 13, 11, 6, 4, 10, 8, 18, 0, 11, 12, 10, 0, 
    7, 2, 10, 9, 10, 8, 10, 8, 21, 11, 6, 3, 25, 17, 6, 3, 11, 
    8, 7, 3, 14, 9, 16, 0, 10, 11, 7, 6, 13, 5, 12, 8, 8, 11, 
    5, 3, 11, 9, 13, 15, 10, 12, 16, 5, 27, 28, 7, 7, 11, 5, 
    26, 25, 7, 0, 6, 7, 5, 7, 16, 16, 9, 4, 18, 14, 6, 6, 22, 
    0, 10, 0, 7, 0, 10, 8, 7, 5, 8, 6, 7, 6, 11, 2, 6, 8, 24, 
    22, 8, 7, 9, 11, 14, 5, 10, 7, 9, 10, 5, 9, 13, 2, 10, 7, 
    16, 0, 18, 8, 8, 10, 21, 20, 5, 8, 6, 5, 9, 10, 7, 2, 14, 
    6, 10, 7, 9, 10, 9, 11, 5, 3, 11, 10, 5, 5, 16, 6, 8, 20, 
    5, 6, 6, 4, 5, 0, 10, 9, 6, 1, 9, 6, 17, 9, 14, 10, 11, 8, 
    12, 17, 10, 7, 12, 8, 7, 2, 27, 23, 22, 27, 12, 9, 6, 9, 
    10, 5, 9, 5, 6, 6, 20, 18, 11, 0, 9, 5, 5, 0, 23, 0, 15, 
    13, 13, 6, 24, 26, 24, 3, 10, 9, 12, 7, 17, 4, 14, 6, 5, 
    2, 12, 6, 7, 10, 6, 2, 10, 8, 14, 1, 10, 5, 8, 4, 10, 7, 
    19, 12, 11, 9, 0, 0, 8, 6, 11, 5, 6, 10, 14, 9, 18, 0, 9, 
    2, 20, 24, 8, 8, 10, 6, 21, 0, 8, 9, 5, 4, 27, 20, 10, 8, 
    8, 2, 28, 28, 8, 2, 11, 7, 10, 10, 8, 5, 10, 10, 10, 7, 8, 
    8, 6, 5, 7, 7, 16, 0, 21, 23, 11, 3, 10, 10, 7, 8, 5, 8, 
    5, 0, 6, 4, 6, 0, 10, 0, 9, 17, 7, 8, 10, 10, 6, 3, 9, 0, 
    12, 0, 18, 0, 11, 8, 13, 3, 10, 7, 9, 6, 6, 2, 12, 8, 7, 
    6, 15, 8, 20, 9, 18, 3, 13, 6, 16, 2, 10, 14, 6, 4, 5, 5, 
    10, 4, 6, 6, 10, 8, 11, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4, 7, 4, 9, 14, 12, 11, 
    15, 4, 14, 11, 9, 4, 11, 5, 13, 13, 5, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2, 6, 
    5, 8, 0, 17, 7, 13, 12, 10, 0, 6, 1, 13, 16, 7, 0, 6, 3, 
    10, 8, 12, 8, 9, 4, 16, 6, 26, 19, 7, 10, 14, 13, 12, 0, 
    8, 3, 12, 5, 8, 6, 7, 2, 9, 7, 22, 11, 17, 13, 12, 10, 8, 
    6, 11, 8, 9, 8, 12, 15, 5, 0, 5, 5, 28, 28, 9, 15, 12, 5, 
    8, 4, 10, 0, 7, 8, 8, 4, 7, 6, 10, 4, 7, 3, 10, 5, 15, 16, 
    16, 16, 9, 7, 7, 28, 7, 4, 13, 15, 10, 12, 14, 12, 13, 10, 
    7, 4, 13, 4, 4, 5, 17, 19, 14, 0, 15, 10, 7, 4, 4, 0, 12, 
    11, 12, 3, 9, 0, 7, 11, 14, 11, 12, 0, 23, 14, 7, 6, 28, 
    28, 12, 5, 12, 1, 5, 1, 13, 11, 9, 4, 6, 6, 10, 10, 7, 0, 
    10, 8, 12, 8, 7, 0, 5, 9, 7, 0, 5, 3, 4, 0, 14, 14, 7, 8, 
    18, 14, 11, 9, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 0, 8, 8, 9, 11, 10, 6, 10, 
    7, 9, 3, 14, 6, 5, 6, 28, 28, 20, 11, 7, 0, 11, 4, 7, 0, 
    13, 7, 11, 9, 11, 0, 16, 8, 8, 3, 19, 11, 14, 0, 6, 0, 21, 
    11, 7, 9, 8, 4, 17, 5, 11, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 12, 5, 22, 18, 
    11, 5, 18, 12, 8, 0, 8, 8, 16, 12, 5, 0, 9, 8, 18, 10, 15, 
    15, 7, 0, 19, 20, 16, 0, 15, 9, 5, 0, 11, 9, 8, 0, 25, 26, 
    10, 16, 13, 8, 21, 20, 10, 8, 10, 0, 15, 14, 13, 15, 19, 
    0, 10, 11, 14, 1, 25, 2, 12, 5, 5, 2, 5, 3, 5, 10, 12, 7, 
    8, 8, 25, 26, 10, 15, 9, 8, 10, 6, 3, 3, 13, 0, 16, 9, 24, 
    4, 16, 13, 14, 1, 12, 6, 7, 5, 9, 6, 11, 7, 5, 0, 12, 8, 
    6, 11, 17, 11, 22, 0, 1, 3, 25, 15, 9, 3, 7, 0, 6, 0, 10, 
    19, 7, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 10, 16, 15, 21, 8, 4, 28, 28, 3, 4, 
    17, 8, 3, 2, 18, 11, 9, 0, 8, 10, 1, 6, 16, 17, 3, 2, 6, 
    0, 6, 4, 13, 10, 11, 9, 2, 0, 13, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 7, 4, 10, 
    1, 11, 0, 12, 5, 12, 4, 9, 1, 11, 3, 2, 3, 11, 9, 4, 0, 11, 
    6, 13, 5, 5, 13, 21, 0, 8, 8, 9, 0, 10, 0, 5, 9, 11, 0, 6, 
    0, 9, 0, 12, 3, 10, 0, 11, 5, 14, 11, 9, 0, 10, 0, 16, 0, 
    9, 10, 5, 4, 10, 0, 2, 0, 18, 7, 5, 3, 7, 7, 4, 0, 8, 0, 
    7, 0, 2, 0, 27, 0, 6, 4, 8, 10, 19, 3, 5, 0, 8, 10, 11, 11, 
    8, 0, 8, 1, 2, 0, 9, 15, 9, 5, 6, 0, 21, 0, 7, 10, 10, 10, 
    7, 2, 9, 4, 6, 3, 9, 0, 13, 1, 11, 6, 19, 5, 18, 0, 6, 1, 
    15, 19, 13, 15, 0, 0, 5, 16, 7, 0, 22, 2, 15, 0, 9, 0, 11, 
    1, 2, 0, 5, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 10, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 18, 2, 
    6, 2, 5, 0, 8, 0, 12, 0, 4, 2, 10, 0, 15, 0, 8, 5, 12, 0, 
    6, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 9, 0, 4, 0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 11, 0, 20, 0, 8, 
    0, 2, 0, 16, 0, 3, 0, 8, 0, 17, 0, 18, 0, 16, 0, 5, 0, 10, 
    0, 14, 0, 6, 0, 10, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 12, 0, 8, 0, 5, 
    0, 8, 0, 18, 0, 15, 0, 5, 0, 18, 0, 12, 0, 20, 0, 1, 0, 3, 
    0, 10, 0, 17, 0, 7, 0, 15, 0, 9, 0, 8, 0, 11, 0, 6, 0, 10, 
    0, 3, 0, 11, 0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0, 11, 0, 27, 0, 15, 0, 9, 
    0, 13, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 10, 0, 14, 0, 8, 0, 3, 
    0, 6, 0, 11, 0, 17, 0, 6, 0, 12, 0, 7, 0, 14, 0, 25, 0, 7, 
    0, 7, 0, 10, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 6, 0, 13, 0, 6, 0, 
    1, 0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 9, 0, 11, 0, 4, 0, 14, 0, 1, 
    0, 5, 0, 10, 0, 9, 0, 14, 0, 18, 0, 12, 0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 10, 
    0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 14, 0, 14, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 5, 0, 14, 
    0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 5, 0, 27, 0, 9, 0, 11, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 
    6, 0, 5, 0, 15, 0, 15, 0, 19, 0, 15, 0, 14, 0, 7, 0, 2, 0, 
    6, 0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 12, 0, 8, 0, 12, 0, 10, 0, 
    10, 0, 11, 0, 9, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 18, 0, 4, 0, 18, 0, 12, 0, 
    20, 0, 8, 0, 11, 0, 9, 0), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -1290L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the formula so it doesn't know which test to run. Try adding `formula = outcome ~ group*time`

So the code reads

```
rstatix::anova_test(data = test1, formula = outcome ~ group*time, 
dv = outcome, 
wid = id2, 
within = c(group, time))

ANOVA Table (type II tests)

      Effect DFn  DFd       F        p p<.05      ges
1      group   1 1286   0.806 3.70e-01       0.000626
2       time   1 1286 303.565 3.35e-61     * 0.191000
3 group:time   1 1286   0.309 5.78e-01       0.000240
```

This was just a quick example, check out the rstatix anova_test documentation to make sure you're using the right formula for the right test.

**EDIT**
Slow day so I thought I would try your data with the repeated measures as you wanted but it just gave the error, I have no idea why all the data looks good. The following code should work, though its an interpretation of linear mixed model. This seems to be stronger and more flexible than the repeated measures anova and a lot of papers are moving over to this method instead. A quick google should tell you why.

You don't need to install or run the report function but it gives a pretty useful interpretation of the model. I won't paste the output here as there is a lot of it, but worth checking out.

```
devtools::install_github("easystats/report")
library(report)
install.packages("lmerTest")
library(lmerTest)
fit <- lmer(outcome ~ group*time + (1|id), data=test1)
anova(fit)
report(fit)
```

This should give you the following output: anova(fit):

```
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
           Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF  F value Pr(>F)    
group        10.3    10.3     1   643   0.5613 0.4540    
time       9846.7  9846.7     1   643 538.0482 <2e-16 ***
group:time   10.0    10.0     1   643   0.5474 0.4597    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```