# group_by %>% anova_test inconsistency in DFn DFd

Tags: r, anova, rstatix

I have an unbalanced repeated measures design that I would like to run separate ANOVAS for each time period (i.e. Curve) and then Bonferroni correction results for.

Here is the data, where Curve is the repeated measure:

```
T_data <-structure(list(mod_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), Curve = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L), .Label = c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", 
"Sixth"), class = "factor"), Treatment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("GH", "T1", "T2", "T3"), class = "factor"), 
    Topt = c(28.85, 29.83, 29.89, 28.26, 29.2, 29.1, 31.06, 32.24, 
    33.03, 31.1, 32.51, 31.91, 31.42, 31.92, 32.02, 33.75, 32.87, 
    32.76, 28.15, 28.2, 30.89, 29.62, 29.74, 29.36, 29.41, 28.36, 
    29.41, 32.53, 33.03, 31.44, 31.15, 32.15, 32.87, 30.79, 32.75, 
    32.75, 35.02, 30.34, 33.68, 35.01, 32.61, 31.16, 32.11, 30.28, 
    30, 31.86, 29.49, 28.96, 31.29, 32.11, 30.98, 31.92, 31.41, 
    31.09, 32.9, 32.54, 33.16, 33.99, 34.18, 34.14, 28.67, 26.96, 
    27.9, 24.8, 30.76, 28.56, 29.05, 27.08, 29.32, 32.96, 34.25, 
    34.25, 32.17, 31.4, 31.09, 34.68, 33.65, 33.96, 33.04, 33.12, 
    34, 33.18, 34.3, 34.46, 34.02), A_at_Topt = c(20.36, 18.25, 
    18.62, 15.51, 21.39, 16.95, 21.73, 14.43, 16.29, 16.52, 17.65, 
    18.68, 22.13, 21.77, 20.97, 17.75, 19.83, 18.32, 12.6, 17.72, 
    16.91, 19.22, 19.05, 20.49, 16.36, 16.81, 16.48, 21.29, 19.92, 
    18.2, 16.09, 21.56, 19.56, 17.09, 16.71, 20.65, 20.2, 25.19, 
    21.46, 22.63, 22.18, 21.9, 17.86, 16.34, 17.85, 16.25, 20.65, 
    22.92, 19.16, 17.77, 19.5, 20.1, 21.5, 24.58, 22.88, 14.97, 
    20.52, 22.77, 19.96, 16.91, 17.82, 18, 13.13, 16.43, 13.09, 
    11.07, 7.2, 12.87, 12.99, 17.28, 17.04, 21.78, 19.2, 16.42, 
    18.35, 12.51, 18.72, 17.01, 17.75, 19.62, 19.28, 15.32, 19.24, 
    17.22, 17.6)), row.names = c(NA, -85L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This issue I am having is with the `rstatix` package and the `anova_test()` function.  It runs just fine for the Topt variable.

```
library(rstatix)
Topt_bonf <- T_data %>%
  group_by(Curve) %>%
  anova_test(dv = Topt, wid = mod_id, within = Treatment) %>%
  get_anova_table() %>%
  adjust_pvalue(method = "bonferroni")
Topt_bonf
```

This gives:

| Curve | DFn | Dfd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Third | 2 | 10 |
| Fourth | 2 | 12 |
| Fifth | 2 | 10 |
| Sixth | 2 | 14 |

However, the same code gives an odd result for the Aopt variable, where the DFn and DFd are not correct for Curve = "Fifth".

```
Aopt_bonf <- T_data %>%
  group_by(Curve) %>%
  anova_test(dv = A_at_Topt, wid = mod_id, within = Treatment) %>%
  get_anova_table() %>%
  adjust_pvalue(method = "bonferroni")
Aopt_bonf
```

This gives:

| Curve | DFn | Dfd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Third | 2 | 10 |
| Fourth | 2 | 12 |
| Fifth | 1.07 | 5.35 |
| Sixth | 2 | 14 |

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to edit your sample data? It doesn't seem to contain a variable named 'Treatment'?

Comment: indeed, my apologies.  Treatment was not in data. I have updated the data, now.  any ideas @xilliam?  Thank you

Comment: You have a typo in each code block concerning the data objects.  The sample data is 'T_data' by line 2 of code block one uses 'Tdata'.  And we don't have 'Aopt.df' from code block 2.  It's best to edit these.

Comment: got it.  Thanks for the keen eye @xilliam

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are seeing is not a consequnce of using `group_by()`. Instead, it's due to Greenhouse-Geisser correction. So, let take a subset of 'T_data' to simplify. Here we'll look at the data
subset for Curve == 'Fifth'.

```
# subset
T_data_sub <- T_data[T_data$Curve %in% "Fifth",]
```

Using this, with your original code, `anova_test()` is performing a Type III ANOVA,
based on the `car::Anova()` function.

```
> anova_test(data = T_data_sub, dv = A_at_Topt , wid = mod_id, within = Treatment)
ANOVA Table (type III tests)

$ANOVA
     Effect DFn DFd     F     p p<.05   ges
1 Treatment   2  10 0.726 0.508       0.079

$`Mauchly's Test for Sphericity`
     Effect     W     p p<.05
1 Treatment 0.131 0.017     *

$`Sphericity Corrections` # HERE IS WHERE THE DIFFERENT DEGREES OF FREEDOM COME FROM
     Effect   GGe     DF[GG] p[GG] p[GG]<.05   HFe     DF[HF] p[HF] p[HF]<.05
1 Treatment 0.535 1.07, 5.35  0.44           0.562 1.12, 5.62 0.446
```

Because the p-value for Mauchly's Test for Sphericity is significant, the degrees of freedom are adjusted with Greenhouse-Geisser correction. That's why your second screenshot has different degrees of freedom than the first.

If you instead specify a formula to specify the model, `anova_test()` performs a Type II Anova based on stats:aov().

```
> anova_test(data = T_data_sub, A_at_Topt ~ Treatment, wid = mod_id, within = Treatment) 
Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
ANOVA Table (type II tests)

     Effect DFn DFd     F    p p<.05   ges
1 Treatment   2  15 0.642 0.54       0.079
```

Notice in this cases, the `wid` and `within` arguments don't effect the output when a formula is used. It's just doing a one-way ANOVA.

```
> anova_test(data = T_data_sub, A_at_Topt ~ Treatment) 
Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
ANOVA Table (type II tests)

     Effect DFn DFd     F    p p<.05   ges
1 Treatment   2  15 0.642 0.54       0.079
```

Comment: Very well.  Thank you for the explanation.  indeed car::anova() and stats:aov(), are different functions.  That explains it.  Thank you very much, @xilliam

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that the anova_test() function did not have a formula argument so it got confused.

using  dv~var  lm notation fixed the issue.

See the following post:

[Unexplained error with anova_test from rstatix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65952026/unexplained-error-with-anova-test-from-rstatix)

```
Aopt_bonf <- T_data %>%
  group_by(Curve) %>%
  anova_test(A_at_Topt~Treatment, wid = mod_id, within = Treatment) %>%
  get_anova_table() %>%
  adjust_pvalue(method = "bonferroni")
Aopt_bonf
```